# Conversion From String to NSURL constantly returns nil

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to fetch the path of an audio file that I have added to the main bundle of my app. When I print the path as String it prints normally.

But, when I try to print the NSURL of the same after converting it, returns a nil

```
let audioPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "mp3")!
    print(audioPath)

    let audioPathURL: NSURL? = NSURL(string: audioPath)
    print(audioPathURL)
```

Comment: Could not add an image because of my low rep, The console O/P reads as: /Users/Supratik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEABF725-E10A-4090-87EA-15A2E0E87541/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/19BDBDB2-AA46-402E-BE72-0BE47034D15A/Playing With Audio.app/Test.mp3
nil

Comment: You are using the wrong `NSURL` initializer. Use the one that expects a file path, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the filePath specific initialiser

```
let audioPathURL: NSURL? = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

An URL in the file system must be initialized with the method `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` not `NSURL(string:)`.

Or you use the URL based methods of `NSBundle`